# Python partial function doesn't execute

Tags: python, map-function, partial-application

I'm new to using `partial` functions in Python. Here's a piece of simple code, and I am expecting it to print out results, but somehow it doesn't print anything, or say otherwise show that `firstfunc` gets executed:

```
from functools import partial

class zebra(object):
    def firstfunc(self, a, b, c):

        res = 3*a + 55*b + c
        print(res)
        return res

    def partial_func(self, a, c):
        return partial(self.firstfunc, b = 2)


myzebra = zebra()
alist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
blist = [7, 8, 9, 11]

map(myzebra.partial_func, alist, blist)
```

Comment: what is the problem? you can't execute `firstfunc`? as it's defined in the commented line or what?

Comment: hi, i am expecting it to print out 393
451
509
622, but it doesn't print out anything, seems like whatever in firstfunc never get execute

Comment: @viva: `map()` calls `myzebra.partial_func`. `map()` cannot know that you wanted it to call the returned `partial()` object *too*.

Comment: @viva: and presumably this is Python 2, not 3, because in Python 3 `map()` loops lazily (it is a iterator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myzebra.partial_func()` *is* called, and it returns a partial function object. If you wanted it that to be called *as well*, do so in `myzebra.partial_func()`:

```
def partial_func(self, a, c):
    return partial(self.firstfunc, b = 2)(a=a, c=c)
```

or use a lambda in the `map()` to call it for you:

```
map(lambda a, c: myzebra.partial_func(a, c)(a=a, c=c), alist, blist)
```

Note that because you made `b` a keyword parameter, you'll have to pass *at least* `c` as a keyword parameter too.

`map()` won't recursively call objects; only the outermost object is called.

In Python 2, the code now works:

```
>>> map(lambda a, c: myzebra.partial_func(a, c)(a=a, c=c), alist, blist)
120
124
128
133
[120, 124, 128, 133]
```

In Python 3, `map()` loops lazily, so you need to iterate over it for it to execute:

```
>>> list(map(lambda a, c: myzebra.partial_func(a, c)(a=a, c=c), alist, blist))
120
124
128
133
[120, 124, 128, 133]
```